# pure javascript method to set x scroll position in a div with overflow-x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

How to set the x-position of scroll of a div with horizontal/overflow-x with pure javascript or angularjs ? Important: I'm not looking for jquery solutions - using angularjs,jquery wont work straightaway.

$anchorScroll() in angularjs scrolls to a vertical position but not to a horizontal position afaik. 
$window.scroll to or window.scrollTo(x,y) doesnt scroll within an overflow-x div. If anyone here is certail that methods I have tried would work under certain modifications, I would like to know as well.

Comment: [scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollLeft)

Comment: @hindmost I tried some stuff with scrollLeft but it didnt work. Maybe I was doing it wrong. Would love to listen more about it.

Comment: Without any code I can only guess about your problem

Comment: @hindmost, i was using this 

document.getElementById ('target_div').scrollLeft=amount-x-move;

I will post more in my original quesion with more details in a while.

Comment: @hindmost: you're right, scrollLeft works. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$(selector).scrollLeft(amountToMove);` on jQuery

`document.getElementById(containerId).scrollLeft = amountToMove;` using pure javascript or

`angular.element(selector).scrollLeft(amountToMove);` using angularjs.

Comment: You were asked for pure js, why offer jquery?

Comment: I just write the three ways on the answer, Just that.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this wile i was looking for cross browser solution to this problem!
I figure it out that scrollBy on elements only works for Firefox!
I know it is an old question but maybe someone also look for this like me...
Lets say div id is scroll :

```js
    function ScrollByLeft() {
          document.getElementById("scroll").scrollBy(10, 0);
    }
    function ScrollByRight() {
          document.getElementById("scroll").scrollBy(-10, 0);
    }

    function ScrollLeft() {
          document.getElementById("scroll").scrollLeft=10;
    }
    function ScrollRight() {
          document.getElementById("scroll").scrollLeft=-10;
    }
```

```css
div#scroll {
 width: 180px;
 overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll">
<p>
    Scroll.strange.wery.long.word.horizontally.for.10.pixels.left.and.right.also.but.only.on.Firefox.as.I.know</p>
</div>
<button onclick="ScrollByLeft()">ScrollBy Left!</button>
<button onclick="ScrollByRight()">ScrollBy Right!</button>
<br>
<button onclick="ScrollLeft()">ScrollLeft Left!</button>
<button onclick="ScrollRight()">ScrollLeft Right!</button>
```

Limitation:
ScrollBy works only on Firefox as I know...
Other browsers can only scroll window this way!
NOT other elements...